# Find files indented with spaces

Tags: bash

How could I find files in current directory recurcive which are indented with spaces?

I'm trying to write build step on CI to fail build if wrong files indentation was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -rl '^  ' --include=*.{java,xml} --exclude-dir=target > wronglyIndentedFiles.txt
```

Comment: Looks quite familiar, quite useful and quite correct. Good luck with your scripting `:)`

Comment: Hi David! It is really pity that SO cumunity has become so agressive. I'm even more frastrated because there were no reason for such aggressiveness. If this would be first time I would break my head why my previous post got 4 downwotes and was closed (as question is pretty much the same and pretty much usefull). But this is not first time and I'm kind of get used to such scenarious. If you duplicate you ansver here, I'll accept it. Thanks a lot for helping few days ago!

Comment: It's really kind of a "phase-of-the-moon" thing. Sometimes you have roving groups of "downvote weenies" that seem to appear out of nowhere. Other times you get the "thinking group" that is here more to help rather than make themselves feel better by donwvoting others. It's hit or miss. Don't worry about the downvotes too much -- they pretty much come out in the wash. Just do a good job and lead by example -- the other group seems to wax and wain over time. (but there is an open question of form -- whether it is proper to post a question in order to answer it? Use sparingly)

Comment: Your solution works well. Another option is to use `ag` (the silver searcher), which has at least one important advantages over `grep` when working with source code repositories: it respects .gitignore, so it doesn't show results that don't really matter, and works quite a bit faster. Example usage: `ag -l '^  ' --java --xml --ignore some_dir_or_pattern >wronglyIndentedFiles.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve by using `find` command like this

```
find ./parent/path/to/search -type f -name '* *'
```

Hope this helps you.